# Multiple search forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

Is it possible to do 3 separate search forms in one model and view?

at present I have the following in my view:

```
<%= form_tag games_path, :method => 'get' do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :game_name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

and the following in my model:

```
def self.search(search)
 if search
   find(:all, :conditions => ['game_name LIKE ? OR genre LIKE ? OR console LIKE ?', "%#   {search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%"])
 else
   find(:all)
 end
end
```

What I want to do is separate the model in to three parts so that it is not all in one form e.g.

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    find(:all, :conditions => ['genre LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
  else
    find(:all)
  end
end

def self.search(search)
   if search
    find(:all, :conditions => ['console LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
  else
    find(:all)
  end
end

def self.search(search)
  if search
    find(:all, :conditions => ['game_name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
  else
    find(:all)
  end
end
```

and then in my view have x3 of my above view code so that there is one search for name, one for console and one for genre? How would I go about doing this? I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of stuff becomes quickly a mess. For this very reasons, you should go for a more maintainable solution with the help of a gem like [meta_search](https://github.com/ernie/meta_search).